# Load Landsat data from specific months using the Open Data Cube

Tags: landsat, open-data-cube

I have a 32 year Landsat time series Open Data Cube query and I am interested in pulling out only two months per year of data (August and Feb).

Is there any way extracting data per month with the `dc.load`, or following the `dc.load`?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to GIS Stackexchange. It will increase the likelihood of getting a (useful) answer to share what you've tried already, and what portal/platform you are running the time series query on. Finally it might be obvious, but clarifying what 'dc load' might turn out to be helpful context for those answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***August 2021 update:*** As of [version v1.84](https://github.com/opendatacube/datacube-core/releases/tag/1.8.4), `open-data-cube` itself now supports passing directly filtering data before loading it by passing a predicate/filter function to `datacube.load()`'s new `dataset_predicate` parameter. For example, to load satellite data from February and August only:

```
import datacube

# Connect to datacube
dc = datacube.Datacube(app='Filtering_datasets')

# Create a predicate function for filtering satellite data.
# This returns True only if the dataset's month is Feb (2) or 
# August (8):
def filter_feb_aug(dataset):
    return dataset.time.begin.month in (2, 8)

# Load satellite data using predicate function to filter to specific months
ds = dc.load(product='ga_ls8c_ard_3', 
             lat=(-35.0, -35.1), 
             lon=(148.0, 148.1), 
             time='2018',
             measurements=['nbart_red'],
             dataset_predicate=filter_feb_aug,
             output_crs='EPSG:3577',
             resolution=(-30, 30),
             group_by='solar_day')

# Verify that only August or February satellite observations remain 
print(ds.time)
```

---

***June 2021 answer:*** The `predicate` functionality in the `load_ard` function from [dea-tools](https://github.com/GeoscienceAustralia/dea-notebooks/tree/develop/Tools) lets you do this! Essentially you can pass in a custom function and it will filter data prior to actually loading it - there's some examples here that show how to use `load_ard` to extract only data from a single month or season: https://docs.dea.ga.gov.au/notebooks/Frequently_used_code/Using_load_ard.html#Filtering-data-before-load-using-a-custom-function

<strike>If you want to do something similar with `dc.load` itself it's a little trickier: you'll need to identify the data you want to load with `dc.find_datasets`, then loop through the resulting list and keep only the individual datasets that match your criteria. The filtered list can then be loaded with `dc.load` using the datasets param.</strike> *(see above update)*

You can see this working in the `load_ard` source code:

1. Where it identifies all the datasets to load for a given query: https://github.com/GeoscienceAustralia/dea-notebooks/blob/develop/Tools/dea_tools/datahandling.py#L308
2. Where it filters that list based on the `predicate` func: https://github.com/GeoscienceAustralia/dea-notebooks/blob/develop/Tools/dea_tools/datahandling.py#L328-L329
3. And finally, where that filtered list of datasets is given to `dc.load`: https://github.com/GeoscienceAustralia/dea-notebooks/blob/develop/Tools/dea_tools/datahandling.py#L342

Here's a simple code example that works on the Digital Earth Australia instance of the Open Data Cube:

```
import datacube
from dea_tools.datahandling import load_ard

# Connect to datacube
dc = datacube.Datacube(app='Filtering_datasets')


# Create a predicate function for filtering satellite data.
# This returns True only if the dataset's month is Feb (2) or 
# August (8):
def filter_feb_aug(dataset):
    return dataset.time.begin.month in (2, 8)


# Load satellite data using predicate function to filter to specific months
ds = load_ard(dc=dc,
              products=['ga_ls8c_ard_3'],
              lat=(-35.0, -35.1),
              lon=(148.0, 148.1),
              time='2018',
              measurements=['nbart_red'],
              predicate=filter_feb_aug,
              output_crs='EPSG:3577',
              resolution=(-30, 30),
              group_by='solar_day')

# Verify that only August or February satellite observations remain
print(ds.time)
```

[image: Output of filtered data load]